# CSS Button background color not appearing on iPad

Tags: html, css, ipad, button

Having an issue with the following CSS/HTML -- the buttons are appearing fine on Desktop, iPhone, and Android mobile devices but when testing the iPad the button background color is hidden/not visible. The CSS interactions with the button and the button text are still visible, but the background-color is missing.

Here is the Code:

```css
.button-wrap {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-top: 7%;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #E98191;
}

.button {
  width: 100px;
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 0 26px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255) !important;
  border-radius: 100px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin: 2%;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 3px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.005);
  transition: .2s all;
}

.button span {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.button-wrap:hover .button {
  filter: blur(3px);
  opacity: .5;
  transform: scale(.98);
  box-shadow: none;
}

.button-wrap:hover .button:hover {
  transform: scale(1);
  filter: blur(0px);
  opacity: 1;
  box-shadow: 0 8px 20px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.125);
}
```

```html
<div class="button-wrap">
  <div class="button">
    <span>Yes</span>
  </div>
  <div class="button">
    <span>No</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What version of iOS is on the iPad ? Is it the same as on the iPhone you tested ?

Comment: It looks good on ipad, There is no problem with provided code, can you check your `media queries` or provide them in question ?

Answer (score 1):

Plz try this code..

**css**

```
button {
  -moz-appearance: none;
}
```